# Skip a task with gradle.properties

Tags: gradle

To skip a task I can write

```
./gradlew assembleDebug -x countDebugDexMethods
```

Can I factor out this option to a configuration file, namely `gradle.properties`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply disable the task in your `build.gradle`

```
countDebugDexMethods.enabled = false
```